# How to change font of all \structure in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

How does one change the font of only the `\structure{}` elements globally in the preamble in a beamer class, let's say to italics?

I was hoping that `\setbeamerfont{structure}{shape=\itshape}` does the trick, but it changes the frame titles as well. `\setbeamerfont{local structure}{shape=\itshape}` seems to have no effect.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \structure{make me italic!}
    \item \structure{me too!}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

\end{document}

Comment: That is because many elements inherit it's font from `structure`, but you can always redefine them `\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{parent=structure,size=\Large}` without the `parent=structure` entry.

Answer (score 2):

As `structure` is used as parent of many elements, you might have to redefine more than just the frametitle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{structure}{shape=\itshape}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{shape=\normalfont,size=\Large}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \structure{make me italic!}
    \item \structure{me too!}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For others using `alert` instead of `structure` may be a less work intensive alternative.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamerfont{alerted text}{shape=\itshape}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item \alert{make me italic!}
    \item \alert{me too!}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, `\alert` will not work since I use this for other purposes. I was not aware that `\structure` is used for other things internally. I thought this is just a way to highlight something more softly than with `\alert`.

Comment: @Daniel I edited my question to go with your original `structure` command, but you might encounter other places which will be affected.